# How to make users only talk once in a channel?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to figure out how to let members only talk once in a specific channel. When I use the `.overwrite` command an error appears stating:

```
client.overwritePermissions(
           ^ TypeError: client.overwritePermissions is not a function
```

I also only want it to work in one channel, but no luck for that has come to me.

Here's the rest of my code.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '';

let lastUser = undefined;


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', message => {

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    lastUser = `${message.author}`
    client.overwritePermissions(
        lastUser,
        { 'SEND_MESSAGES': false },
    )
  
  
});






client.login(''); //bot token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.overwritePermissions()` does not exist, but it does exist for [channels](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions).
overwritePermissions, as the name and docs would suggest but I failed to understand, *overwrites* the last value. Therefore, in order to continually add new users to the overwrites, you need to copy the previous value then add onto that:

```
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.name == "support") {
        let ow = message.channel.permissionOverwrites.array(); //get the information of the current permission overwrites, as an array
        ow.push({ //add our data object to the end of this array
                id: message.author.id,
                deny: ["SEND_MESSAGES"]
            });
        message.channel.overwritePermissions(
            ow //pass this array as our new overwrites
        );
    }
});
```

`overwritePermission` takes an **array** of **objects**. These are the objects we push onto the previous overwrites.
The objects are documented [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/OverwriteData).

Comment: When someone else talks it allows the user to send messages.
Also how do I let it only work in one channel

Comment: I don't know what you mean about someone else talking allowing the user to send messages, but to make it only work in one channel, you should copy the channel ID from your discord server, then in code compare `message.channel.id == "YOUR CHANNEL ID"`, or alternatively `message.channel.name == "YOUR CHANNEL NAME"`, make that an if statement and only override perms inside that. I'll update the answer to include this.

Comment: The channel now works, but as I said before if another user sends a message, it allows the person who is muted to send a message again.

Comment: I understand now and I've replicated the issue. I will update the answer and post a comment when I know the solution.

Comment: @BilalAhmed I have fixed the error. I tested it myself with 2 users and it works.